# Importing CSV with 60k columns into BigQuery

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I have a few CSVs that have 60k+ columns that I'm trying to import into BigQuery. But when doing so, I get the following error:

`Too many values in row starting at position: 0. Found 65535 column(s) while expected 3.`

I have set up the schema to have three columns because it's only the first three that I need from the CSV. So one solution I could think of would be to limit the import to select columns, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Another idea would be to question why there are so many columns in the first place. The reason is that these CSVs contain a lot of text (they were originally text files), and all the commas are being interpreted as separate columns, unsurprisingly.

Any suggestions how to be able to get the information from the first three columns into a table or alternatives would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you removed column names from your csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ignoreUnknownValues](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options) flag.

> (Optional) Indicates if BigQuery should allow extra values that are
> not represented in the table schema. If true, the extra values are
> ignored. If false, records with extra columns are treated as bad
> records, and if there are too many bad records, an invalid error is
> returned in the job result. The default value is false. The
> sourceFormat property determines what BigQuery treats as an extra
> value:

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the speedy response, that did it! I had done that through the web interface which led to other issues, but with bq load it worked. Thanks for making me see!